# MySQL Workbench - migration of the data doesn't work

Tags: mysql, migration, workbench

I'm trying to do a migration through MySQL Workbench, from one server to another.  It sets the schema okay, but when it comes to the data, it fails.  It doesn't give me much information either - the output resembles this:

```
`schemaname`.`GeneralCodes` has FAILED (0 of 3 rows copied)
```

That's all it says.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How are you migrating the data?  Are you doing a Data Export from one and a Data Import to the other, or are you doing this with some SQL queries, or something else?

Comment: I'm migrating the data using MySQL Workbench.  It has an option called "migrate" under "Database" which is supposed to be automatic.

Comment: I was able to find this open bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66135, and [googling](https://www.google.com/#q=has+FAILED+(0+of++rows+copied)+MySQL+Workbench) finds a lot of people with your same problem.  Maybe this is a common issue.  I would suggest to try another way of migrating data?  Perhaps Data Export/Data Import in the Admin tab.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  (I should have said that before.)  I've tried exporting/importing the data from one place to another, and it failed on the import saying "The network name cannot be found."  I checked the server names, and they were okay. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the "The network name cannot be found" message meant, at least.  I was using the network at work to store my dump files, as in "\\myserver\horndinkle\dumps\xxx".  It was referring to **that**, that MySql Workbench couldn't read from there, not the network name I was migrating to/from.  Once I put the file on my local machine, it worked just fine.